# Proxied HTTP response being modified

Tags: node-http-proxy

I have a gulpfile that launches a dev proxy server.

```
gulp.task('dumbserver', ()=> {
    const express = require('express');
    const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
    const app = express();
    const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

    app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
        proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api', secure: false},
            (e) => console.log('error', e)
        );
    });
    return app.listen(8080, function () {
        console.log('Server started on port 8080.');
    });
});
```

When I make a call on postman directly to `https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api/session` I get the following payload:

`<Session  locationId="86171c79-e8f0-4c06-a0a8-4bc7fde76915@7bcf706c-d90f-4e1b-b0cc-b2a13db3e618" org="juan" roles="System Administrator" user="administrator" userId="urn:vcloud:user:7b5f0241-f597-4851-8cae-655a15afde24" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api/session" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.session+xml">
    <Link rel="down" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api/org/" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.orgList+xml"/>
    <Link rel="remove" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api/session"/>
    <Link rel="down" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api/admin/" type="application/vnd.vmware.admin.vcloud+xml"/>
    <Link rel="down" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/api/admin/extension" type="application/vnd.vmware.admin.vmwExtension+xml"/>
    <Link rel="nsx" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/network" type="application/xml"/>
    <Link rel="openapi" href="https://bos1-vcd-sp-static-199-8.eng.vmware.com/cloudapi" type="application/json"/>
</Session>`

However, when I make a call using postman to `localhost:8080/api/session`, the last two links have the hrefs rewritten to be

```
<Link rel="nsx" href="https://localhost:8080/network" type="application/xml"/>
<Link rel="openapi" href="https://localhost:8080/cloudapi" type="application/json"/>
```

But none of the other links have been rewritten.

Any suggestions about what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `http-proxy` adds a *HOST* header. The server side code that was generating the links was using that *HOST* header if available  as the base URL, overriding the configured value.

Not deleting the question in the hopes that the knowing fact that http-proxy adds a host header to requests may cause a bug in your code.